# Interpreting GLM Interaction Contrasts in R (using glht)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, multiple-comparisons, glmm, contrasts

I am trying to do a BACI analysis on count data, and I am having trouble interpreting the output from  multcomp::glht.   I don't understand how the contrast's coefficients are related to effect size (if at all??).

I have 5 treatment conditions (one is a control), and I have counts from before the treatments were applied and after. Let's say that my model form is this ("Period" is the 'before' vs 'after' factor):

```
m.pois <- glm(Y_count ~ Treatment + Period + Treatment:Period,
                   data = df.temp,
                   family = "poisson")
```

As in all BACI designs, I am interested in the iteraction term, i.e., the differences of the differences.  For example, I'd like to test whether TreatmentVR30 changed more than the Control did:
   (TreatmentVR30Later - TreatmentVR30Before) - (ControlLater - ControlBefore).

I have done the math, and I created all my planned contrasts, run them through the multcomp::glht, and I am struggling to interpret the output.  As an example of my confusion, I ran the same contrast in two directions (A-B and B-A), which should give the same result (one positive, one negative):

```
contr <- rbind(
  "VR30 vs Control" =     c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1),
  "Control vs VR30" =     c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1)  )
m.pois.contr <- summary(glht(m.pois, contr))
```

which works perfectly, returning one positive and one negative estimate, as expected:

```
Linear Hypotheses:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
VR30 vs Control == 0   0.7354     0.5621   1.308    0.191
Control vs VR30 == 0  -0.7354     0.5621  -1.308    0.191
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Understanding that the estimates are in log space (due to the link function of the poisson family in the glm), I back transformed using exp(coef(m.pois.contr) to get:

```
VR30 vs Control Control vs VR30 
      2.0862414       0.4793309
```

So, which is it?  Did Control change more than VR30, or did VR30 change more than Control, and for both questions, by how much?

Clearly I am missing something here.  I expect that this will be a simple fix, but surprisingly, I cannot find it anywhere online.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help,

David Robichaud, Victoria, BC, Canada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mis-interpreting the exponentiated estimates - they are a (multiplicative) rate.

`VR30` would have 2.09x as many `Y_count` as `Control`, and `Control` would have 0.48x as many `Y_count` as `VR30`. Notice they are inverses of one another -
$ {1 \over 2.09} = 0.48 $